# NIC shows "No Connection" in Windows 11 - works in Linux

Tags: networking, windows-11, wired-networking

My NIC, an Intel® I218-V Gigabit LAN controller built into my Asus Z97 Sabertooth motherboard became unstable today (Using windows 11). Switching around some cables would make the connection come back and then appear as disconnected.

I booted up from a live USB with Manjaro and it worked fine, but slowly (~100Mbit according to iperf3). I figured out that there was an issue with the cat5E cable, so I replaced it and I got consistent 1000Mbit performance in Manjaro Linux.

I rebooted my computer, and the network appears completely offline (except for the fact that it does have an IPv4 address (I use DHCP) and DNS is filled out correctly.

Also I went into device manager and disabled "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" after which that dialog hangs.

There IS another Gigabit port (Realtek® 8111GR Gigabit LAN controller). If I switch the network cable to that the PC does not get an IP in Windows - indicating that the

This is a rather fresh (< 14 days) install of Windows 11.

I am quite puzzled, especially since it works as expected in Manjaro Linux

### Update:

- Updating drivers made no difference. Both the newest from Asus and the newest from Intel.
- Disabling the Realtek NC in BIOS made no difference.
- I unplugged another cable (connected to another PC which is currently off) from the switch (router in WAP mode) and suddenly I got a connection in Windows... maybe that other PCs NIC was causing issues even in off mode...

Comment: Try downloading an updated Windows LAN driver from ASUS and installing it. Do a restart of Windows after that.

Comment: @John Tried that - no success

Comment: I would say (1) if Linux works and (2) driver update does not, then there is something wrong with your Windows 11 OS.  Try an in place Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: I tried installing the newest drivers from Intel as well... no luck.

Comment: I unplugged another cable (connected to another PC which is currently off) from the switch (router in WAP mode) and suddenly i got a connection in windows...

Comment: So this is a cable problem.

Comment: yes, but oddly enough not the cable used to connect the PC with the issue - just a cable connected on the same switch